# Dropdown button on navbar won't work?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, erb

I'm trying to get my navbar to scale to a dropdown menu when the screen is made smaller. The dropdown menu does appear on a smaller screen, however, when I press the dropdown menu, nothing happens. It's supposed to present the navbar options up but this isn't happening, I'm wondering what I may be doing wrong.

This is my code in my application.html.erb file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <title>FYP</title>
  <meta name = "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">



  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>





  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/r29/html5.min.js">
      </script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body>




<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <%= link_to "SL League", welcome_index_path, id: "logo" %>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <% if current_user %>
            <li><%= link_to current_user.email, user_path(current_user.id) %> </li>
            <li><%= link_to "Log Out", logout_path %></li>
        <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign Up", signup_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Log In", login_path %></li>
        <% end %>
        <li><%= link_to "Home",   welcome_index_path %></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>


<div class="container text-center">
      <%= yield %>

</div>



<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
<%= content_tag(:div, class: "alert alert-#{key}") do %>
<p><%= value %></p>
<% end %>
<% end %>


</body>
</html>
```

I also have imported bootstrap into my application css file but this doesn't do anything either.

Comment: I think in your css it is defined to open drop down upon hover and on small devices hover is not working.

Comment: I'm trying it on my web browser as well just by making the browser smaller and it still doesn't acknowledge anything when I press the dropdown button.